# Will GNOME Online Accounts ever support Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, online-accounts

Like the title of the question says, is Ubuntu One integration with GNOME Online Accounts on the roadmap for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not on the roadmap of both of them.

Not trying to guess stuff out and say *no* but the short answer will be that: *no, not that its known atm*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real question is "Will Ubuntu One ever support GNOME Online Accounts?"

I do not believe it is planned for either of the projects, but I would recommend asking a developer of either projects if they could add the feature before ubuntu 12.04 (should be able to find a dev at launchpad)